# creating new column in R using ifelse

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I'm really new to R, so excuse my question, it might seem stupid.
I want to create a new column in R using the dplyr function.

```
Gender Value 
boy      2
girl     3
girl     2
```

This the table that I have. I want to create a new  column that has as one condition the gender and then either the Value or a 0. Kind of like this:

```
gender  Value  Girl 

boy      2       0
girl     3       3
girl     2       2
```

So far I have the function: `df1 <- mutate(df, Girl= ifelse(Gender==  "girl",Value,0))`

But that way, it doesn't assign the Value to the column, I just get 0's. Do you know a way  to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that there are some leading/lagging spaces.  Also, the code showed that the OP was creating the logical condition in `Gender`.  In the expected, the column name was lower case (`R` is case sensitive)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(Girl = ifelse(trimws(gender) == "girl", Value, 0))
```

Comment: @csarvf_01 can you show the `dput(head(df1$gender))`